# What's the best way to tell if the mouse is over a form or not?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mouseover

I figured out [how to capture mouse clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866936/how-can-i-add-an-event-handler-to-an-event-by-name) over the entire form, but this method doesn't translate well for `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave`. My form layout is made up from many `Panels` and `TableLayoutPanels` so there's no all-encompassing control I can monitor events for, and obviously a `MouseLeave` event for a button doesn't mean the cursor left the entire form. Has anyone figured out a good way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone pointed out [here](http://www.windows-tech.info/3/fb723e773ebfb936.php) it's possible to use SetWindowsHookEx() or just hook up MouseMove event onto all controls in the form. The latter works for me fine. The only downside is if you add/remove controls at runtime you might need another solution.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsForms_MouseEvents
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MouseMove += OnMouseMove;
            MouseLeave += OnMouseLeave;

            HookMouseMove(this.Controls);
        }

        private void HookMouseMove(Control.ControlCollection ctls)
        {
            foreach (Control ctl in ctls)
            {
                ctl.MouseMove += OnMouseMove;
                HookMouseMove(ctl.Controls);
            }
        }

        private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            BackColor = Color.Plum;

            Control ctl = sender as Control;
            if (ctl != null)
            {
                // Map mouse coordinate to form
                Point loc = this.PointToClient(ctl.PointToScreen(e.Location));
                Console.WriteLine("Mouse at {0},{1}", loc.X, loc.Y);
            }
        }

        private void OnMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BackColor = Color.Gray;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A place to start is to check if the [ClientRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle.aspx) contains the current mouse position. So, for example, on your [MouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx) handler, you could have:

```
if (ClientRectangle.Contains(e.Location))
{
    bool mouseIsOverThisControl = true;
}
```

Comment: Would this work for the entire form, tho? I can see how this would catch `MouseEnter` events, but when the mouse leaves the form, it stops calling `MouseMove` events, so it wouldn't check to see if it's left the form or not, no?

Comment: When do you need to know that the mouse is over your form?

Comment: The entire form acts like a giant button. (It's a notification of an incoming call.) So when the user mouse's over the form, I want it to light up, indicating that pressing it will take the call.

Answer (score 1):

I found a few answers that were close to what I wanted, but I wound up doing something different.  I wanted to detect if the mouse left the form area (including the title bar) and this worked for me:

In the form constructor, I add a timer:

```
time.Interval = 250;
time.Tick += time_Tick;
time.Start();
```

Then in the tick method, I do the following:

```
void time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (RectangleToScreen(Bounds).Contains(PointToScreen(Cursor.Position))) {
        case true:
            if (Opacity != .9999D)
                Opacity = .9999D;
            break;
        case false:
            if (Opacity != .5D)
                Opacity = .5D;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer to the form with a reasonable Interval (maybe 50ms).  Use this code in the Tick event handler to see if the mouse is over the form:

```
// Check if mouse is currently over the form
    bool temp_mof = ClientRectangle.Contains(
       Form.MousePosition.X - Location.X,
       Form.MousePosition.Y - Location.Y);
```

EDIT: Here is a more complete solution to detecting that the mouse is over the form and that the button has been clicked.  `timer1Tick()` is the Tick event handler for a Timer on the form.  There is no need to have additional event handlers for the other controls on the form.  This will make your form "one giant button" :)

```
bool m_mouse_over_form = false;
// Assume the left button is down at onset
bool m_left_button_down = true;

void timer1Tick (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Check if mouse is currently over the form
   bool temp_mof = ClientRectangle.Contains(
      Form.MousePosition.X - Location.X,
      Form.MousePosition.Y - Location.Y);

   // were we already over the form before this tick?
   if (temp_mof && m_mouse_over_form)
   {
       // we need to detect the mouse down and up to avoid
       // repeated calls if the mouse button is held down for more
       // than our Tick interval

       // was the mouse button up prior to now?
       if (!m_left_button_down)
       {
           // is the button down now?
           m_left_button_down = (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left);

           if (m_left_button_down)
           {
               // the button was down and has now been released
               LeftButtonClickHandler();
           }
           else
           {
               // do nothing, the button has not been release yet
           }
       }
       else
       {
           // update the button state
           m_left_button_down = (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left);
       }
   }
   else if (temp_mof)
   {
       // the mouse just entered the form

       m_mouse_over_form = true;

       // set the initial state of the left button
       m_left_button_down = MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left);
   }
   else
   {
       // the mouse is not currently over the form
       m_mouse_over_form = false;
       m_left_button_down = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: -1: Please do not do this. SlavaGu gives a very good answer..explore Api calls if you must. Just don't do this. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

Do A MouseEnter and MouseLeave event over the Form and Form Controls; use a boolean to determine whether the mouse entered or left.

An example would be

```
    private static bool mouseEnteredForm

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseEnteredForm = true;
        Form.MouseLeave += Form1_MouseLeave;
        CheckMouseLocation();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseEnteredForm = false
        CheckMouseLocation();
    }

    private static void CheckMouseLocation()
    {
        if(!mouseOverForm)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Mouse Not Over Form!);
        }
        else if(mouseOverForm) //else if is optional. You could also use else in this case. I used else if for the sake of the example.
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Mouse Is Over Form");
        }
    }
```

This may get tedious if you have many objects over the form