# Mouse position on screen

Tags: c#, mouse, mouseevent, mousemove

I have a form, with a textbox in it. When I start my application I want that textbox to contain the cursor position on screen, even if the cursor is out of my form. How can I do this?

My code is the following but it works only when the cursor is on the form:

```
protected override void OnMouseMove( MouseEventArgs e )
{
    mousePos.Text = Cursor.Position.ToString();

    base.OnMouseMove( e );
}
```

Comment: Is this you want?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874710/whats-the-best-way-to-tell-if-the-mouse-is-over-a-form-or-not

Comment: @Alvin Wong helped me to solve this, so I will accept the answer as far as I can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` with an interval of 100 milliseconds, and put your function inside the `Timer.Tick` event handler.